# Best potato varieties to use for mashing

Tags: potatoes

I use Maris Piper with butter, milk and seasoning, but I'm wondering if there is a better variety for mashing?

Comment: In the UK, I haven't found a better mashing potato than Albert Bartlett Roosters. But I find any potato works, especially if you use a potato ricer and a dangerous amount of butter.

Comment: I'll be sure to try these ones next time. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

The variety of potato used for mashing really is a matter of preference, and the style of product you desire.

#### Light, Fluffy Mashed Potatoes

The best potatoes for light, fluffy, very smooth and elegent mashed potatoes are starchy varieties, such as the US Idaho.

#### Dense, Creamy Mashed Potatoes

For dense, creamy mashed potatoes (which also hold longer), a waxy potato like a Red Bliss or a fingerling is more ideal.

#### Middle of the Road

You can also get excellent results with middle of the road potatoes which are between the starchy and waxy extremes, such as the US Yukon Gold.

Comment: I invite people to add varieties for other regions besides the US.

Comment: I believe a more specific term for what you are calling "US Idaho" are russet potatoes.

Comment: Nearly every county in the world uses different names for the same/similar potato variety. This is unanswerable by name, you need to to use other factors. Like the look and texture of the potato when it is cut and boiled. How do you test for starchy or waxy, what are you looking for? Do all varieties give the same results at throughout the growing season?

Comment: Thanks. Got to say I find that dense and creamy mash tends to sit heavily in my belly, as delicious as it is.